# Symfony2 when listeners are preferable than services?

Tags: symfony

I know, that in most cases services preferable, because they are initiated directly at the call site and this approach making code more clear.

While harder to reason, what a system doing, when things are spread out over events.

1. **When using listeners is better than using services?**
2. **How to use listeners and keep code clear?**

Please, give some examples. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should really use services in your listeners. Create the service to encapsulate a method/action/etc and then call that where ever it is needed, controller/listener/command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listeners make sense when you create a reusable bundle/component that should not be modified by its clients but still be extensible.

Listeners don't make much sense for application code because they add a level of indirection that makes it harder to figure out what's going on.