# Limit access to the route

Tags: symfony

I'm new in symfony2 and I'm currently facing a problem. I would like to restrict the access on some of my page based on some dates contained in my database.
For example all the page after my **mon.site/home/** would be redirect on an error page. I have already thinking on a event listener, but don't know how to restrict on some URL. Is there a better way to implement this function? If not how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite straightforward to me. You can choose between two different solutions

## First solution

1) Create a [custom event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html#creating-and-dispatching-an-event) and [event subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html#creating-an-event-subscriber).
2) Dispatch event you've created at 1) everywhere (in every action) you need an extra control
3) Inside the event subscriber call for a method into custom event or directly a method of the subscriber to check if the "request satisfy your needs"
4) Raise an `AccessDeniedException`.

## Second solution

1) With [DependencyInjection](https://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/dependency_injection/index.html) create a custom configuration where you can specify what controller's actions should be checked for the condition you wish
2) Create an [EventListener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html#creating-an-event-listener) that listen for kernelRequest event
3) Into EventListener just check for condition
4) Raise an `AccessDeniedException`.

Answer (score 0):

For restricting access you can use:

- [voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) (and also using different strategies of access decision
  manager)
- you can also restrict access for whole sections of your app, using
  [access_control](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html) option in your security.yml
- you can also use [acl](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html)

[try to avoid using listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33575877/5397119).

**P.S.** and also if this not enough you can configure `.htaccess`